# Add css style when other plugin overwrite it

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `div` and I want to add border to this `div`:

```
function addBorder() {    
    $('#nav').css({'border:left':'100px solid red;'})
}
```

But, this `div` uses other plugin which move it. This plugin uses style attribute and overwrite my style. How to solve it?

Comment: This might be stupid, but perhaps you should add `!important` between the "red" and ";". I'm not exactly sure what you are asking so I can't exactly answer correctly.

Comment: @PatchGuru: it's not help, because plugin overwrite all style attribute.

Comment: What plugin are you using that is overwriting your style attributes?

Comment: @PatchGuru: The `Sidr`. http://www.berriart.com/sidr/. You can check demo. The plugin is write `display` and `right` properties to the style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc you can create your own stylesheet for the plugin...

I would take one of the original scss files (https://github.com/artberri/sidr/tree/master/src/scss), adapt it to fit what I want and replace the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="javascripts/sidr/stylesheets/jquery.sidr.dark.css">` to mine...

It should do the trick

Hope this helps

Have swing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function addBorder() {    
    $('#nav').css({'border-left':'100px solid red !important;'})
}
```

or css

```
#nav{
border-left:100px solid red !important
}
```

i have changed your **border:left** to **border-left**. and added !important